# How to design utility webservices consumer class(es)

Tags: java, singleton, static-methods, webservices-client

In a java project i need to call (lets say generic, utility) web services. For instance giving a city code as parameter and getting details about that city. Web services are already implemented and i can only consume them.
I had the same situation before in another project and created a class for that kind of webservices. That class had several web service call methods and all were static methods.

Now, i dont really want to do same thing again because i dont think thats the right way to do it (hard to debug etc). I also dont want to make a different class for all these methods and make an instance for each call because they are too generic and instantiation seems like an overhead for that situation.

So, alternatives comes to my mind is

- Using old method. One static class, several methods.
- Singleton class. Most probably will have syncronisation problems, so will have overhead using locking mechanisms.

Both are not the best solutions what would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you think that a singleton class will give you synchronisation problems?

Comment: because this methods will be called concurrently. I believe i have to manage that singleton for concurrency problems.